# PHP cookies are always empty when trying to access them

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, cookies

So i am setting cookies here. They are totally working since when i go onto my firefox privacy thing, i can see the cookie there and its value, but the moment i am trying to read it or to echo it, it is always giving me a blank result...

I am using Wordpress, and i call the setcookie with an ajax request from a click of a button. Here how i do it under here :

This script is inside templateDirectory/js

```
$('.bucket-list').on("click", function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: templateDir + '/js/list.php'
    });
```

Inside the php file list.php, we have this :

```
setcookie("displaymode", "list" , time() + 3600 * 24 * 30);
```

Up to here as i said i can see the cookie inside my browser, but when i try to call it, it just keep on giving me blank result, like this :

```
if ($_COOKIE["displaymode"] == "list") 
        echo '<div class="class1">' ;
      else {
        echo '<div class="class2">' ;
        echo '<script>';
        echo 'alert('.$_COOKIE["displaymode"].')';
        echo '</script>';
      }
?>
```

this script up there is located in the main file (homepage.php) from the templateDirectory. Any help would and will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you expecting the `if($_COOKIE ...)` code to work when the page is first loaded BEFORE the ajax call is executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the cookie is set on the expected *path*.

If your script is in:

```
/templates/MyTemplate/js/list.php
```

The cookie will be set for the path `/templates/MyTemplate/js/`.

To set the cookie for the *whole* domain use:

```
setcookie("displaymode", "list", time() + 3600 * 24 * 30, "/");
                                         set path to "/" --^
```

Comment: Thanks alot that was the right awnser to my problem. I though cookies were used for everything on the website, my bad for not knowing it all !

Answer (score 2):

Remember that cookies cannot be set and called on the same page. You have to have a page load in between. That's why people tend to gravitate towards sessions, which can be set and called on the same page (the session data is not stored in the cookie)

Comment: Even though that was not what i was looking for, this is crucial information for me to know, and i am welcomming you for sharing this with me. I will keep it in note, thanks alot for helping !

Answer (score 0):

From [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/setcookie), in common pitfalls:

> Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie expires.